# What's the error in this Priority Queue based Generic skeleton? I can't find it

Tags: java, generics, queue, priority-queue, missing-template

Can anyone help me figure out the wrongly typed portion? Which are the problematic areas here?

```
class Queue<E> {
 /**
 * A First in, First Out Queue ADT
 */
 public List<E> elements = new ArrayList<E>();
 public void enqueue(E element) {}
 public E dequeue(E element) {}
 public int size() {}
 public boolean isEmpty() {}
}
class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Queue<E> {
 /**
 * A Queue where each element has a priority
 * Higher priority elements are pushed to the front of the queue
 */
 @Override
 public Object dequeue(E element) {}
 public void enqueue(E element, int priority) {}
}
```

Comment: PriorityQueue.dequeue returns Object, which is less specific than the E of the method it overrides.